# How to convert a STOP message sent to an SMS provider into the "Do not SMS" privacy preference in CiviCRM?

Tags: sms, twilio

Most SMS providers allow you to respond with STOP to indicate that you no longer want to receive SMS messages. If we try to send another message to a phone number that has replied with STOP, it won't go out.

However, it's not clear how this information gets back to CiviCRM, if at all. Does this have to be handled on a per SMS provider basis? Or should we be building a more generic framework to support all SMS providers? Or is there a way I haven't figured out?

For reference - here's how Twilio handles it: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-

Answer (score 3):

Used CiviRules to do this.

This switches the Do Not SMS flag to ON if they reply STOP:
[image]

This switches the Do Not SMS flag to OFF if they reply START:

[image]

Comment: Very nice Guy! Slick. I used Activity details is an exact match to condition just in case a reply back contains stop and start and they aren't intending to opt in or out. It is case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I am surprised the Twilio extension doesn’t have this capability built in.

Comment: The Twilio extension does have this capability built-in now.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably possible to do via an extension, e.g. something similar to https://civicrm.org/extensions/auto-reply-twilio-sms

Otherwise there is a generic "inbound" function that handles incoming sms if the provider lets you set up a callback, e.g. [twilio setup](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/sms-text-messaging/set-up/#setting-up-your-new-mobile-phone-number-in-twilio), and it's implemented in civi via [this code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/60080668785d1e389bd81260bb13210b428f224f/CRM/SMS/Provider.php#L193) and individual sms provider extensions can use it [like this](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.sms.twilio/blob/c324f44365c5fc886d2564891555cd46a00c739f/org_civicrm_sms_twilio.php#L189).

So it seems possible to implement something generic.